# Visual Studio 2013 crashes and restarts every time I run my test solution

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 crashes and restarts every time I run my test solution. When I hit F5 IIS Express starts, the solution builds successfully but after that a dialog box comes up saying Visual Studio is not responding and looking for a solution and then restarts itself.

I tried re-installing IIS express, Visual Studio 2013 but no good.

It is a blank solution and I have not added any code.

Comment: Post the stack trace/errors in the eventlog. did you try with a simple brand new fresh project?

Comment: Yes it is a brand new fresh project.

Comment: no, you misunderstood. Did you try, again, file > new project? were you able to run it, without writing any code?

Comment: Sure. I will try that and post the error log. Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think I figured out how to fix the issue:

Go to:

> Visual Studio 2013 -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Project -> Use 64 bit version of IIS Express

for websites and projects has to be checked if you are using a 64 bit machine.

Comment: I had the same Problem, but not with a Web-Project. to reproduce it, i just need to start visual studio 2013 and close it... it will always crash and start again. this solution solved it! win 8.1 x64  THANKS!

Comment: That was spot on! Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Thanks bro! how did you come to this?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember. But I remember finding some hint in one of the tech forums.

Comment: @StevenSpyrka How did this solution fix it if you had the problem with non-web projects and the solution is related to web projects?

Comment: I am working on NopCommerce, I did the same setting , but when i start debugging(after 64 bit) i get error of No database instance. But when i rollback settings then it again started working but same crash error ! Any other solution is there ?

Comment: It worked for me for a few hours. Started facing the same issue now. Upvoted the answer too soon :D