# Visual Studio 2013 freezes when ending debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

Out of the blue Visual Studio started locking up on me for 2-5 minutes at a time when ending debugging (after a test run, in my case). CPU usage is high (maxing out one core). If I leave it, eventually it will unfreeze and continue as normal.

I've tried a [number of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174767/visual-studio-2013-sp1-hangs-when-trying-to-debug-asp-net-web-site) but nothing seems to help.

- I don't have any add-ons installed
- I tried restarting Visual Studio and my PC
- I rebooted my PC and ran `chkdsk /F`
- I don't have Show All Files turned on in the Solution Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be stupidly simple: I saw a suggestion somewhere (can't remember where, sorry) to clear all breakpoints with Ctrl+Shift+F9. I did that and restarted the IDE for good measure, and so far it's been running fine.