# Visual Studio 2015 Stops Working When Trying To Debug

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, crash, visual-studio-2015

I have recently been having a problem with my Visual studios 2015 in which it stops working when i try to debug anything. I am able to build and rebuild the solution perfectly fine however when i try to debug it it simply stops working and a loads indefinitely. Also when i try to run the exe directly from the debug folder the windows explorer that i am opening it in does the same as Visual Studios. I have tried this with both complicated program and also just a super simple "Hello World" program. the language i am using is Visual C++. Any help would be appreciated because this is really annoying me.

Comment: Please, provide VS build, your OS version, your code to debug... In other case, it's not possible to help you

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0

Windows 10

and the code i tested with was literally just 1 cout with "Hello World"

Comment: Try solutions given by users: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174767/visual-studio-2013-sp1-hangs-when-trying-to-debug-asp-net-web-site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174767/visual-studio-2013-sp1-hangs-when-trying-to-debug-asp-net-web-site). Did you install some extension?

Comment: No it's a fresh install, also i can't find the "Show all files" button in 2015, any help

Answer (score 2):

After openning your VS 2015 and solution project, then if you experience the problem saying 'Visual Studio stopped working, close the program.....'
while you run or build the project that was previously fine; then run the command below in the command prompt

```
    -> Go to command prompt
    -> Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
    -> Then run devenv/resetuserdata
    -> Open the VS2015 and give your MS account for starting VS2015 as new instance
    -> open your solution, build and debug, then ENJOY :)
```