# Debugging ASP.NET site with Chrome 60.0.3112.90 causes visual studio to hang untill developer tools (F12) is opened

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Lately, I've noticed that when debugging my ASP.NET sites, visual studio and the site itself hangs untill I open developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), after which it continues like normally. This does not happen in Microsoft Edge.

I think this may have to do with an update of Google Chrome to 60.0.3112.90, as it has happened on two unrelated computers, with two unrelated ASP.NET MVC projects. On both of these computers I use Visual Studio 2017.

Regular building/publishing works normally, and running my project without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) also works normally. After rebuilding and running without debugging (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26933677/5022761)) it also debugs normally.

Is this a known bug and is there any way to solve this?

Comment: If you use IE as the default browser, how about the result? Whether your app use the JavaScript? If so, as far as I know, we need to enable the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)" under Tools->Options->Debugging->General. Or you could create a simple web site, debug it again.

Comment: If you get any latest information, please feel free to share it, is it related to the new JavaScript debugging option in VS 2017?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT as far as I know I'm not using the Javascript debugging option, so I don't think it is. It stopped happening for me though, so if it was a problem with chrome they updated it (I'm on Google Chrome version 60.0.3112.101 now)

Comment: Maybe it was the old version setup issue even if I couldn't repro it in my side using the old version, anyway, since it has the update version and it doesn't have this issue now, using the newer version would be better:)