# Debugging Web Projects in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: debugging, 64-bit, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

I have some web projects that run fine in the debugger in VS 2012. But when I try to run the same projects in VS 2013 i run into some problems.

First the whole Devenv.exe crashed when pressing F5.
I found an article about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932980/visual-studio-2013-crashes-and-restarts-every-time-i-run-my-test-solution)

It suggests set ISS Express in Visual Studio to 64 bit.
That solved the problem of the whole IDE crashing.

However, with that configuration Visual Studio tries to start "Remote Debugging". Probably because Visual Studio itself is 32 bit, so it must use some "remote" techniques to debug something 64 bit.  At least that's my guess on what is happening.

Remote debugging is not succeeding either. I get "Remote Debugger has stopped Working" sometimes. Sometime at the beginning of the degugging session, and sometime at the end of the session. I found an article about this problem too. It suggest to set the web project to x86 to avoid remote debugging. But that will not work in this case. It has to run 64 bit to work with IIS in 64 bit.

Error message is

```
Remote Debugger has stopped Working
```

Then

```
The debugger's worker process (msvsmon.exe) unexpectedly exited. Debugging will be aborted.
```

Anyone else seen this?
Is this a common problem in Visual Studio 2013?

---

EDIT: more details about the environment

I have a solution containing several projects, including two web projects.
The issue happens when I try to run any of the web projects in debugger (by pressing F5).
They are normal web projects, and I am not running anything remote.

Visual Studio itself came up with the idea of using "Remote Debugger" when I checked the "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects".

The solution was first created on a Windows 7 machine running Visual Studio 2012 and it worked well there.
When I tried to open the same solution on a new machine running Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 the problem started.

A colleague is also running the same solution on his Windows 8.1. We share the solution using a git repository.
He has both VS 2102 and VS 2013 installed. He experiences the same problems in VS 2013, so he has started to use VS 2012 for this solution.
It runs fine in VS 2012. It is the same solution and same machine as it fails in VS 2013.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well in VS 2013. All the "fixes" that I've found by googling all offer ways to fix this in IIS, but being a "reluctant web developer" I have no idea how to apply this to IIS Express, or if it's even possible.

Comment: I'm getting this problem with a custom build of UE4