# Visual Studio 2013 (Cordova Template) after CTP 4 update Crashes frequently

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

After upgrading Visual studio 2013 to CTP4 and using the Cordova template, my visual studio freezes each time I click save and force me to restart it.

With CTp3 the multi device hybrid app template was working fine. any one having same issue or work around?

Comment: Do you mean that you upgraded your VS 2013 to Update 4 and then installed the latest Tools for Apache Cordova extension which is CTP3.0?  Our previously available extension was CTP2.0 which was dependent on VS 2013 Update3.

Comment: Thanks Ellen, yes I was referring update 4 and CTP3. I fix from other person.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932980/visual-studio-2013-crashes-and-restarts-every-time-i-run-my-test-solution

I think I figured out how to fix the issue:

"Go to: Visual Studio 2013 - Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Web Project - Use 64 bit version of IIS Express for websites and projects has to be checked if you are using a 64 bit machine."

Comment: I set "use x64". It not work for me. Every save freeze VS to 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Surfacing an answer from one person in the comments, this may resolve the issue for some people using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 with the Cordova tools:

Visual Studio 2013 crashes and restarts every time I run my test solution

Separately, the RTM release of Visual Studio 2015 and the Tools for Apache Cordova is now available and that may fix this issue. If you still have this problem, I suggest submitting a bug report on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.