# Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013 CTP3 crashes or gets freezed

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, crash, visual-studio-cordova

I'm experiencing not that random crashes and freezes in Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013 CTP3. I've also updated to Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Visual Studio has this issues after I debug or open the whole app either to the browser using Apache Ripple or Android emulator.

When I save some file (f.e. a JS file), it crashes - sometimes it crashes without my intervention too -. The error is the well-known generic crash which prompts you to restart or debug the application (Visual Studio).

Do you know any further step I can perform to make this more stable? I know that it's a CTP, but it's impossible to build and application restarting Visual Studio every 2-5 minutes...

I've found this other Q&A [Visual Studio 2013 (Cordova Template) after CTP 4 update Crashes frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098397/visual-studio-2013-cordova-template-after-ctp-4-update-crashes-frequently), but my case is a fresh upgrade to Update 4 and later I've installed Cordova Tools CTP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: Visual Studio 2013 - Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Web Project - Use 64 bit version of IIS Express for websites and projects has to be checked if you are using a 64 bit machine.

Source:
[Visual Studio 2013 crashes and restarts every time I run my test solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932980/visual-studio-2013-crashes-and-restarts-every-time-i-run-my-test-solution)

Comment: I'm going to give this a try!

Comment: You've saved my bucket! I was going to buy a new Android to avoid these issues. I believe I'll be able to develop a big part of my mobile app in browser using Ripple thanks to this fix. BTW it seems like my question is a duplicate of your source... I will vote to close it

Comment: I thought it solved the issue, but after some hours the issue is still happening :(

Comment: If this is still occurring, could you please send a dump file to vscordovatools@microsoft.com?

1. Run another instance of VS.
2. Debug | Attach to Process.
3. Locate devenv.exe
4. Pick 'Native + Managed 4.5' for attachment.
5. Debug | Break All.
6. Debug | Save dump.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt help me and I am crashing every single time i build. Even on a fresh project. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if ripple is running and you try to modify code it freezes.

Answer (score 2):

i described solutions (works for me) here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28670917/4506880

Hope it helps.