# Visual Studio 2013 Cordova App Build Error - Freezes

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I'm not being able to build a Cordova app in Visual Studio 2013. The build starts but freezes a couple of seconds later.

This last output line from the build process:

> Could not find Cordova as a local module. Expecting to find it
>   installed globally.

[image]

I've countless times ran the Cordova install command (globally) on node.js and still get the same build error.

[image]

I'm not sure how to get around this issue.

Does anyone has an idea what's the problem or what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem and i tried bunch of solutions... The problem was salved by change settings in my firewall. I observed that the firewall blocks one of js process(node.exe). When I **turn off firewall the VS unfreezes**. So I reconfigured it and my problem disappeared. I use win 7 64 bit, and VS 2013 update 4.

You can also try switch on the x64  IIS(if you're using 64bit OS):  [Cordova Tools for Visual Studio 2013 CTP3 crashes or gets freezed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133123/cordova-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-ctp3-crashes-or-gets-freezed)

and/or update the Web Essentials Nightly: 
http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=3989

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I ended up switching to debugging in a virtual machine on VMWare - And 'voila' - No more problems !